# ContextConfiguration does not inject config file when running the Test

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have this configuration class in a maven project:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Configuration
public class SmsConfig {

    @Value("${sms.domainId}")
    private String domainId;

    @Value("${sms.gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl;

    @Value("${sms.cmd}")
    private String cmd;

    @Value("${sms.login}")
    private String login;

    @Value("${sms.passwd}")
    private String passwd;

}
```

and this other class

```
Service("smsService")
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl implements SmsService {

    private final SmsConfig smsConfig;

    public AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl(SmsConfig smsConfig) {
        this.smsConfig = smsConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendSMS(String msg, String to) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

That I want to test using this file:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SmsConfig.class })
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl smsService;

    @Test
    public void testSendSMS() throws Exception {
        smsService.sendSMS("this is a test", "+34653776498");
    }

}
```

but I have a nullpointerException because `smsConfig` is null when running the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use spring runner to run the test case so that spring beans can be injected.

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`